# TYPO3 can't read or create pdf thumbnails with imagemagick or graphicsmagick

Tags: windows, pdf, imagemagick, typo3, thumbnails

I'm using `TYPO3 CMS 7.6` with `PHP 5.5.2` on a **Windows Server 2012** (IIS), my Server administrator installed `ghostscript`, `graphicsmagick 1.3.25` and `imagemagick`. Now I use `graphicsmagick`:

```
C:/GraphicsMagick/gm.exe
```

It works, test all graphic manipulation on install tool: Convert image formats to jpg or scaling or combining images ... only PDF Thumbnails or convert PDF to JPG isn't working.

Screenshot:[image]

Error:
    Read pdf

```
Image generation failed
ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick handling is enabled, but the execute command returned an error. Please check your settings, especially ['GFX']['im_path'] and ['GFX']['im_path_lzw'] and ensure Ghostscript is installed on your server.
```

The path to `gm` or `im` is correct, because the other formats are working fine.

```
[GFX][im_path] = C:/GraphicsMagick/
[GFX][im_path_lzw] = C:/GraphicsMagick/
```

Me and my system admin don't know why TYPO3 can't create PDF Thumbnails in backend and frontend. Maybe there's something with ghostscript .. but he can create pdfs via windows command line?!? So that's a TYPO3 Problem?!

Thanks for your help or hints. ..

No PDF Thumbnails , see backend

[image: pdf preview backend]

Comment: check wether the php-tmp path is writable for the php-user. I don't know if that can occur on windows. it's a common mistake on our linux-servers.

Comment: hi bernd. I'll give the info to my admin. But he said, that he can read and write PDF-Files via Command Line. So, Ghostscript is working. I guess TYPO3 is missing the path to Ghostscript..?!

Comment: I think my path to Ghostscript is wrong. In C.\GraphicsMagick\delegates.mgk was sth. like ` <delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command=""@PSDelegate@"` maybe I have to change the command to `C:\gs\gswin32c.exe` f.e..

Comment: This issue is still unsolved. The path wasn't the problem. PDF and AI is still not working with `TYPO3` and `Windows Server`. Does somebody still have an idea? I will make a new instance with linux and will test it.

Comment: you may look [here] (http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15056) where the problem is based on differences between 32bit and 64bit application / configuration.

Comment: thanks bernd, I will inform my server admin .. maybe he can solve the problem. Thanks for your comment. I will update this post, If it works.

Comment: Now, we have installed all applications with 64bit. IIS, `GraphicsMagick 1.3.23` and `Ghostscript 9.22`. Still nothing, TYPO3 cannot convert PDF -> jpg. We test on server console `"c:\program files\GraphicsMagick\gm.exe" - convert c:\temp\Test.pdf c:\temp\Test.jpg`and it works. TYPO3 didn't find the right path to ghostscript, I don't know?!

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue in the policy.xml file for Imagemagick reading PDFs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 1):

with installing **GraphicsMagick** also install **Ghostscript** on window Server. You can download Ghostscript from here https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html. Before downloading please check also the window is 64 bit or 32 bit.Then again check Environment>image Processing and Test Image. Then in "Image processing" everything is loaded successfully also "Read pdf" and "Read ai"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will inform my system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I have still the same problem. My `TYPO3 7.6.24 LTS` will not convert PDF- and AI-files to jpg. All other files are working.

Today I've update `ghostscript 9.22` and `graphicsMagic 1.3.23` on my windows server (IIS). Everything runs with 64bit now.

Successfully, I also tested GraphicsMagick to convert the pdf to jpg via command line `cmd.exe`, f.e.

```
"c:\Program Files\GraphicsMagick\gm.exe" -convert -geometry 160x130 c:\temp\test.pdf c:\temp\test123.jpg
```

But it won't work with TYPO3, see error on initial post ... now I've no idea anymore ..?! anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you also set the path of GraphicsMagick in TYPO3 admin panel settings>Configuration Presets>Image handling settings>write a path or select a path it should be like this screenshot as below [image]