# ImageMagick not authorized to convert PDF to an image

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, imagemagick

I have a program, in which I need to convert a PDF to an image using Image Magick. I do that using the `subprocess` package:

```
cmd = 'magick convert -density 300 '+pdfFile+'['+str(rangeTuple[0])+'-'+str(rangeTuple[1])+'] -depth 8 '+'temp.tiff' #WINDOWS
if(os.path.isfile('temp.tiff')):
    os.remove('temp.tiff')
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
im = Image.open('temp.tiff')
```

The error I got is:

```
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `temp2.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `temp.tiff' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UKExtraction2.py", line 855, in <module>
    doItAllUpper("A0","UK5.csv","temp",59,70,"box",2,1000,firstPageCoordsUK,boxCoordUK,voterBoxCoordUK,internalBoxNumberCoordUK,externalBoxNumberCoordUK,addListInfoUK)
  File "UKExtraction2.py", line 776, in doItAllUpper
    doItAll(tempPDFName,outputCSV,2,pdfs,formatType,n_blocks,writeBlockSize,firstPageCoords,boxCoord,voterBoxCoord,internalBoxNumberCoord,externalBoxNumberCoord,addListInfo,pdfName)
  File "UKExtraction2.py", line 617, in doItAll
    mainProcess(pdfName,(0,noOfPages-1),formatType,n_blocks,outputCSV,writeBlockSize,firstPageCoords,boxCoord,voterBoxCoord,internalBoxNumberCoord,externalBoxNumberCoord,addListInfo,bigPDFName,basePages)
  File "UKExtraction2.py", line 542, in mainProcess
    im = Image.open('temp.tiff')
  File "/home/rohit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2609, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp.tiff'
```

The most important of which is:

```
convert-im6.q16: not authorized `temp2.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
```

I think this is because ImageMagick isn't authorized to access the PDF. What should be done now? I'm on a Linux server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please review [Security Policy](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php) in the documentation. You'll need to enable support by editing a `policy.xml` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP ImagickException: not authorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599727/php-imagickexception-not-authorized)

Comment: It looks like a temporary patch to safeguard against this security vulnerability: https://bugs.gentoo.org/664236 so it should "go away" and "just work" again at some point. In the mean time you have the choice of either being unable to use imagemagick for some formats, or having a vulnerability (which you get by following the suggestions below).

Comment: One more thing, if possible, people should look into using GhostScript directly, instead of ImageMagick, as it an do the same task of PDF conversion much  much faster than IM.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 109, accepted):

emcconville is correct. More specifically edit the Imagemagick policy.xml file to uncomment this line:

```
  <!-- <policy domain="module" rights="none" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" /> -->
```

And change it from rights="none" to rights="read|write"

```
  <policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" />
```

This was a recent addition to the policy.xml file, I believe, due to a security flaw found in the Ghostscript delegate. I think that flaw has now been fixed in the current version of Ghostscript, which is 9.25.

NOTE: On some systems the policy line will have domain="coder" rather than domain="module"

Comment: On Mac Homebrew I had to remove PDF from `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="{EPS,PS2,PS3,PS,PDF,XPS}" />`

Comment: Why did you have to do that? Did it not work to just uncomment it and change the rights to "read|write"?

Comment: I didn't have a commented line like you did. I searched the whole file for PDF, and it was in the line I mentioned

Comment: This should have worked. `<policy domain="module" rights="read|write" pattern="{EPS,PS2,PS3,PS,PDF,XPS}" />`. Note I changed domain="coder" to domain="module". Perhaps Homebrew miscoded it with the wrong term?

Comment: Maybe. But removing it from `none` rights also works too :) not sure the security implications of that, but I just wanted to document what I had to do to get my script working

Comment: Can you try my suggestion above? Note that I edited it as I see yours had domain="coder" and mine has domain="module". If you cannot do that, then that is OK. I understand what you did. I am not sure of the implications of your approach either.

Comment: Where is this file?

Comment: `@rudolfbyker` What file? Are you talking about the policy.xml file? If so, see https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 on `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` near the end I had to change the rights from none to `domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF"`.

Comment: Some versions of ImageMagick use coder and others module in the policy.xml file. I am not sure why it was changed. But this is the same solution as I posted above except in my command the policy.xml file used module.

Comment: make sure to update ghostscript https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/

Comment: the policy options get evaluated from top to bottom, so you have to add the "ps,pdf,xps"-right under the existing restrictions or comment out those restrictions.

Answer (score 49):

Quick and easy solution:

```
sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml.off
```

When done, you can restore the original with

```
sudo mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml.off /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. However, I suggest replacing `rm` with `mv`, and will try to edit your answer.

Comment: This mv out and back in solution is great!  I use this undo-restore now around all my numerous convert commands in scripts involving pdf files.  Reliable again after despair.  Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I am using Dockerfile to update an image, and suddenly I got the policy.xml file in my way. although the version of Ubuntu (xenial) was the same and ImageMagick as well.

I ended up removing the single line causing my problem.

`RUN sed -i 's/^.*policy.*coder.*none.*PDF.*//' /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks for this, it was the exact fix I needed!

Answer (score -2):

Use the below command to delete the policy file to fix it, If required you can also take backup of this policy file.

```
rm /etc/<ImageMagick_PATH>/policy.xml
```

for me it was ImageMagick6 and the command was :

```
sudo rm /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Comment: That's a little drastic.

Comment: Drastic indeed. Rather delete/modify the questionable line.