# ImageMagick no decode delegate for this image format `PDF' Windows

Tags: windows, imagemagick

Trying to play with ImageMagick to read scanned PDF texts, but at the point to convert the PDF to image, I've got this error, where it shows "no decode delegate for this image format `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504". Been search for this solution for hours to no avail, need some help here.

OS: Windows 7 x64

ImageMagick Version: ImageMagick-6.9.8-10-Q16-x86-dll.exe

```
convert -list format
```

shows below output

```
   Format  Module    Mode  Description
-------------------------------------------

* native blob support
r read support
w write support
+ support for multiple images
```

Comment: Have you installed **ghostscript** (`gs`) with matching 32/64 bit-ness?

Comment: You may have to modify your policy.xml file for the recent addition of a restriction on PDF files due to a Ghostscript bug that has subsequently been fixed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes i do have ghostscript installed.

Comment: @fmw42, this does not work for me..

Comment: What do you get back for `convert -version`? What do you get for `gs --version`? If your output for `convert -list format` does not show anything further, then you have a problem with your install. It should list a lot of image formats.

Comment: `convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.8-10 Q16 x86 2017-06-11 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pa
ngocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your delegates are not properly configured,
Once Ghostscript is installed make sure the binary folder `C:\Program Files/gs/gs3.0.9/bin` is added to your path.

Once Done, there should be a file names delegates.mgk in you graphics magick home directory. Open that file in a text editor.

`<delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command='"@PSDelegate@" -q -dBATCH -dSAFER -dMaxBitmap=50000000 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=@GSEPSDevice@ "-sOutputFile=%o" -- "%i" -c quit' />`

In the whole file, find and replace `@PSDelegate@` with `gswin64c` and it should get the job done.