# Imagemagick convert pptx to jpg failing in ghostscript call

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

Have recently upgrade to imagemagick 7.0.8-14 and have lost the ability to convert a pptx file to a jpg(or any other file format). Was working version before upgrade.  The below is the out put from running the convert cmd. Happens on all pptx that have been run against it.

`imagemagick version: 7.0.8-14`
`ghostscript version: 9.07`
`centos 7`

```
$ convert test.pptx[0] -thumbnail 650x650 -gravity center -extent 1500x1000 s1.jpg

\convert /tmp/magick-17292VzAbA_mfaxJX -> /tmp/magick-17292VzAbA_mfaxJX.pdf using filter : impress_pdf_Export
convert: PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library 9.07] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72' -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-17292RtJq2Z8iF5iK%d' '-f/tmp/magick-17292wskX7eyNic7t' '-f/tmp/magick-17292jHMWYZOpLjVd'':    **** Warning: Dropping incorrect smooth shading object.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
Error: /rangecheck in --run--
Operand stack:
   -1   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1867   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:946/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:109/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:292/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:27/32(L)--   --dict:6/8(L)--   --dict:21/40(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 @ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/276.
convert: no images defined `s1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3288.
```

Comment: Not sure this is the issue, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413. Ghostscript 9.07 is rather old. You might upgrade. I believe the current version is at least 9.25

Comment: I'd need to see the PDF file to comment, but that message sequence says 'something is wrong with your PDF file'. While normally I would agree with the comment from fmw42, currently upgrading Ghostscript to the most recent version will not help. You could try version 9.24, that might work for you.

Comment: I agree with KenS. Some newer versions of Ghostscript have had problems. But 9.23 was a good one for me.

Comment: Perhaps your destination folder is not writable by imagemagick. Seem to have the same error, but need to do further investigation at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

could you share your current version of Ghostscript by running the below command?

`rpm -qa ghostscript`

In case the version is anything above and including 9.07-31.el7_6.1, could you try to downgrade to 9.07-31 and report if it is fixing your problem? To downgrade to that version, run the below command:

`yum downgrade ghostscript-9.07-31.el7`

If this was fixing your problem, I would be more than happy if you could share the pptx file with me (if possible).

For more info, see:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1657694

This problem should be fixed now with a release of ghostscript-9.07-31.el7_6.6.

Kind regards,
-Martin

Comment: output: ghostscript-9.07-28.el7_4.2.x86_64