# What is the format of $HOME/.magick, the config file?

Tags: image, graphicsmagick

It is mentioned nowhere on the website. I want to convert hundreds of picture into a pdf, it fails EVERYTIME. I couldn't grop the old imagemagick file either.
I use to do that kind of compilation, can't do otherwise, and I use to do bigger directories.

Thanks for your help.
    gm -version
    GraphicsMagick 1.3.31 2018-11-17 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
    Copyright (C) 2002-2018 GraphicsMagick Group.
    Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
    See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

```
Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     no
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     yes
  JPEG-2000                no
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   yes (201511)
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     no
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     yes
  WMF                      no
  X11                      yes
  XML                      no
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  '--with-quantum-depth=16'

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = gcc
  CFLAGS   = -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread
  CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/include/freetype2
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -pthread
  LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  LIBS     = -ljbig -lwebp -lwebpmux -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng16 -lXext -lX11 -llzma -lz -lm -lpthread
```

Also: I have 6 processors, and lots of memories and hard disks. This thing MUST work !

Comment: Why so angry? Start with just one image and show how you tried to make a PDF from it and what the error message was.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413. There is an ImageMagick policy.xml file that controls security. PDFs have a security entry the restricts its use due to a bug in older versions of Ghostscript, which has since been fixed. But the default policy is now to disallow reading of PDFs unless you edit the policy. Not that in .magick, which is your private location, you can only make the policy more strict. You need to change the main policy.xml file. see https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Comment: Sorry I misread your post. The policy.xml file is for reading PDF. You do not need that for writing PDF in ImageMagick. `convert input.suffix output.pdf` should do that. I do not use GraphicsMagick, so cannot comment on it. But my command does work on ImageMagick.