# Can't convert PDF to jpg using imagemagick and ghostscript

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick-convert

I have imagemagick 7 with ghostscript 9.26 installed on Ubuntu 18. I'm trying to run a simple convert to change a pdf to jpg and I get this error

```
convert -density 100 -colorspace rgb /home/cougs/test.pdf -scale 200x200 /home/cougs/test
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
convert: no images defined `/home/cougs/test' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3300.
```

I have jpg extension installed. If you look at the configure you get this.

```
identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-27 Q16 x86_64 2019-02-13 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): jpeg x
```

It's showing the jpg delegate. I'm not sure it won't work though.

Comment: One of several possibilities. 1) GS is not properly installed. 2) GS 9.26 has some bugs -- try downgrading to 9.23, 9.24 or 9.25. 3) and most likely, you need to edit your policy.xml file to enable processing of PDFs (due to an old GS bug). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 1):

I completely removed GS and Imagemagick. Reinstalled it with GS 9.23 version. It works now.