# RMagick error on upload - Magick::ImageMagickError not authorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using the gem `gem 'rmagick', '3.1.0'` and i am trying to upload a PDF, convert each pages to a jpg and ship the jpgs off to S3. It is currently working on my local environment and my staging server, but not working on my production server. I can't tell right now that anything is different between my staging and production servers.

The code being called:

```rb
images = Magick::Image.from_blob(params[:set_list_item][:attachment].read)
```

The error i'm receiving:

```rb
Magick::ImageMagickError not authorized `/tmp/magick-o0O927WR' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/454
```

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. I have tried some of the suggestions by changing the policies for imagemagick to `read|write` for PDF and HTTPS but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to /tmp? Do you have Ghostscript installed? One other possibility is that you need to modify your policy.xml for PDF access. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Comment: Permissions are the same between the staging and production servers for the `/tmp` directory and i do have Ghostscript installed. I thought changing the policy file would help but even change PDF policy to `read|write` doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Try putting the full path to Ghostscript in the delegates.xml file for PDF where it says `command="&quot;gs&quot;`. Put the path before the `gs`, which is Ghostscript.

Answer (score 3):

Open the file `policy.xml` from location `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and change the rights

```
$ sudo vi /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml
```

Not sure why this worked, and thought I had tried it before but it's working now. I changed both the following lines from `rights="none"` to `rights="read|write"`:

```xml
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PS" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
```

Comment: where did you make this change?

Comment: I see, `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

Comment: In case it helps someone, this worked for me but I had to reboot the computer