# Lambda which reads jpg/vector files from S3 and processes them using graphicsmagick

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, imagemagick

We have a lambda which reads jpg/vector files from S3 and processes them using graphicsmagick.

This lambda was working fine till today. But since today morning we are getting errors while processing vector images using grahicsmagick.

"Error: Command failed: identify: unable to load module `/usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.7.8/modules-Q16/coders/ps.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1278.
identify: no decode delegate for this image format`/tmp/magick-E-IdkwuE' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544."

The above error is occurring for certain .eps files (vector) while using the identify function of the gm module.

Could you please share your insights on this.

Please let us know whether any backend changes have gone through with the aws end for Imagemagick module recently which might have had an affect on this lambda.

Comment: If you are on a shared server, did your hosting provider do any upgrade? If so, you may be running into the PDF/EPS/etc security issue and may need to edit your ImageMagick policy.xml file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Comment: Looks like a revision in Lamdba's ecosystem has removed `ps.la` module. Most likely due to security issues. Might be easier to migrate your solution to a SQS/EC2 combination where you can control (and patch) dependencies.