# User wand by python to convert pdf to jepg, raise wand.exceptions.WandRuntimeError in docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, wand

I want to convert the first page of pdf to an image. And my below code is working well in my local environment: Ubuntu 18. But when I run in the docker environment, it fails and raises:

> wand.exceptions.WandRuntimeError: MagickReadImage returns false, but
>   did raise ImageMagick exception. This can occurs when a delegate is
>   missing, or returns EXIT_SUCCESS without generating a raster.

Am I missing a dependency? Or something else? I don't know what it's referring to as 'delegate'.

I saw the source code, it fails in here: `wand/image.py::7873lines`

```
if blob is not None:
    if not isinstance(blob, abc.Iterable):
        raise TypeError('blob must be iterable, not ' +
                        repr(blob))
    if not isinstance(blob, binary_type):
        blob = b''.join(blob)
    r = library.MagickReadImageBlob(self.wand, blob, len(blob))
elif filename is not None:
    filename = encode_filename(filename)
    r = library.MagickReadImage(self.wand, filename)
if not r:
    self.raise_exception()
    msg = ('MagickReadImage returns false, but did raise ImageMagick '
           'exception. This can occurs when a delegate is missing, or '
           'returns EXIT_SUCCESS without generating a raster.')
    raise WandRuntimeError(msg)
```

The line `r = library.MagickReadImageBlob(self.wand, blob, len(blob))` returns `true` in my local environment, but in the docker it returns `false`. Moreover, the args blob and len(blob) is same.

```
def pdf2img(fp, page=0):
    """
    convert pdf to jpeg image
    :param fp: a file-like object
    :param page:
    :return: (Bool, File) if False, mean the `fp` is not pdf, if True, then the `File` is a file-like object
        contain the `jpeg` format data
    """
    try:
        reader = PdfFileReader(fp, strict=False)
    except Exception as e:
        fp.seek(0)
        return False, None
    else:
        bytes_in = io.BytesIO()
        bytes_out = io.BytesIO()
        writer = PdfFileWriter()

        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(page))
        writer.write(bytes_in)
        bytes_in.seek(0)

        im = Image(file=bytes_in, resolution=120)
        im.format = 'jpeg'
        im.save(file=bytes_out)
        bytes_out.seek(0)
        return True, bytes_out
```

Comment: Most likely you are missing the Ghostscript delegate installed with ImageMagick. ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to rasterize PDF files. There a many posts on this forum that indicate that Docker has failing to install that. Search this forum to find those posts and solutions. Once you get Ghostscript installed, if it does not work, then you may need to edit the policy.xml file to permit PDF files to be used in ImageMagick. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know what it's referring to as 'delegate'.

With ImageMagick, a 'delegate' refers to any shared library, utility, or external program that does the actual encoding & decoding of file type. Specifically, a file format to a raster.

> Am I missing a dependency?

Most likely. For PDF, you would need a `ghostscript` installed on the docker instance.

> Or something else?

Possible, but hard to determine without an error message. The "WandRuntimeError" exception is a catch-all. It exists because a raster could not be generated from the PDF, and both Wand & ImageMagick can not determine *why*. Usually there would be an exception if the delegate failed, security policy message, or an OS error.

Best thing would be to run a few `gs` commands to see if ghostscript is working correctly.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o page-%03d.png -r120 input.pdf
```

If the above works, then try again just with ImageMagick

```
convert -density 120 input.pdf page-%03d.png
```

Comment: Oh, in the docker it not have `ghostscript` default, so it fail. Now i install it, it work well!