# Convert pdf to image on windows 10

Tags: php, windows, pdf, imagemagick

Until the  last windows 10 update I was able to convert pdf files to images with ImageMagick.
This sample code did the work.

```
$imagick = new Imagick();

$imagick->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/111/1.pdf');
```

Now, not only it's not working but I don't even get a php error. 
The browser simply shows a "This site can’t be reached" error.

If i try to read an image and not a pdf file it's working fine.

php version is 7.2.13 
phpinfo() shows that imagick is configured correctly (including the pdf extension)

Comment: There is no output to the browser? How do you expect an error message?

Comment: try catch does not work with ImageMagick

Comment: One possibility is Ghostscript is not installed for ImageMagick to use. Another is an ImageMagick policy issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413