# imagemagick FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin64c.exe" when converting pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am seeing the following error when converting a pdf into another pdf just as a test. This also happens when converting the pdf into any other file format

```
magick convert example.pdf test.pdf
convert: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin64c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dPrinted=false  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/brand/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-MzUgEU_V-cMidHdNrWG2hR56GHegabIj%d" "-fC:/Users/brand/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-ip4WYomlHXJDe5oZnT8WnJ3S-c6NgSe2" "-fC:/Users/brand/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-U7oHzpaPP3SMSPujfBR1lS8_QXa3KII0"' (The system cannot find the file specified.
) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516.
convert: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified.
' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/714.
convert: no images defined `test.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3327.
```

I have installed imagemagick on windows.
Converting from .png or .jpg to .pdf seems to work but converting from .pdf to any other file format doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63844478/376454

Answer (score 1):

Installing GhostScript did the trick. Kudos to *K J*