# no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to convert a pdf file to a png image, but the script does not work.
I use imageMagick Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-35
when I run the command

```
identify test.pdf
```

the error displayed is

```
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
```

when I run `magick -version`
I have `Delegates (built-in): jpeg zlib` gslib is note in the list

however I have ghostscript which is installed on my machine

Comment: Ether you do not have Ghostscript installed or you need to edit your policy.xml file to give permission to read and or write PDF. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413. When you run `magick -version` does it list gs or gslib in the list of delegates?